# How can I convert this long format dataframe into a wide format?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am using `RStudio` for data analysis in `R`. I currently have a `dataframe` which is in a `long format`. I want to convert it into the `wide format`.

An extract of the `dataframe` (`df1`) is shown below. I have converted the first column into a `factor`.

Extract:

```
df1 <- read.csv("test1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

df1$Respondent <- factor(df1$Respondent)

df1

      Respondent  Question      CS             Imp     LOS  Type  Hotel
1          1       Q1       Fully Applied     High     12   SML   ABC
2          1       Q2       Optimized         Critical 12   SML   ABC
```

I want a new `dataframe` (say, `df2`) to look like this:

```
Respondent      Q1CS           Q1Imp     Q2CS        Q2Imp     LOS   Type   Hotel
  1          Fully Applied      High    Optimized    Critical   12   SML    ABC
```

How can I do this in `R`?

Additional notes: I have tried looking at the `tidyr` package and its `spread()` function but I am having a hard time implementing it to this specific problem.

Comment: `tidyr` is not going to be able to do that in a single pass, requiring instead that you do it for each key/value pairing you want to transfer. I'm told the newer (not-yet on CRAN) `tidyr::pivot_*` functions will be better suited for more complex cases, you might check them out at https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr and https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html.

Comment: @jay.sf It is not the same problem as mentioned in that question. Mine has more than one value to convert into the wide format. Hence, that solution cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a `gather`-`unite`-`spread` approach

```
df %>%
    group_by(Respondent) %>%
    gather(k, v, CS, Imp) %>%
    unite(col, Question, k, sep = "") %>%
    spread(col, v)
#  Respondent LOS Type Hotel          Q1CS Q1Imp      Q2CS    Q2Imp
#1          1  12  SML   ABC Fully Applied  High Optimized Critical
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "      Respondent  Question      CS             Imp     LOS  Type  Hotel
1          1       Q1       'Fully Applied'     High     12   SML   ABC
2          1       Q2       'Optimized'         Critical 12   SML   ABC", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

In data.table, this can be done in a one-liner....

```
dcast(DT, Respondent ~ Question, value.var = c("CS", "Imp"), sep = "")[DT, `:=`(LOS = i.LOS, Type = i.Type, Hotel = i.Hotel), on = "Respondent"][]
```

> ```
>    Respondent          CSQ1      CSQ2 ImpQ1    ImpQ2 LOS Type Hotel
> 1:          1 Fully Applied Optimized  High Critical  12  SML   ABC
> ```

**explained step by step**

create sample data

```
DT <- fread("Respondent  Question      CS             Imp     LOS  Type  Hotel
             1  Q1       'Fully Applied'     High     12   SML   ABC
            1   Q2       'Optimized'         Critical 12   SML   ABC", quote = '\'')
```

Cast a part of the datatable to desired format by question
colnames might not be what you want... you can always change them using `setnames()`.

```
dcast(DT, Respondent ~ Question, value.var = c("CS", "Imp"), sep = "")
#    Respondent          CSQ1      CSQ2 ImpQ1    ImpQ2
# 1:          1 Fully Applied Optimized  High Critical
```

Then join by reference on the orikginal DT, to get the rest of the columns you need...

```
result.from.dcast[DT, `:=`( LOS = i.LOS, Type = i.Type, Hotel = i.Hotel), on = "Respondent"]
```